# In Openlayers how do i get the radius of a circle in miles?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I draw a circle on a map in Openlayers and i want to calculate the radius of a circle in miles and display it.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how i ended up doing it.

```
var measure = event.measure;
var areaSquareMiles =  measure * 0.386102;
var radius = 0.565352 * Math.sqrt(areaSquareMiles);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this problem with following code:

```
//vectorLayer.features[0] --> Your circle feature
var central = vectorLayer.features[0].geometry.getCentroid();
var point1 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(central.x, central.y);

var circlePoint = vectorLayer.features[0].geometry.components[0].components[1];
var point2 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(circlePoint.x, circlePoint.y);

var length = point1.distanceTo(point2);

console.log(length * 0.0006213712)
```

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get your question, but if you have the diameter it should not be too hard:
`radius=diameter/2`
If you only have points of the circle and want to find out the radius, you could estimate the diameter by calculating the max distance between the points. There are different solutions depending on the required precision (interpolation). Hope this helps.